# Extracting Jar names from maven projects(using Nexus Rest API)

Tags: java, maven-2, nexus

I have a scenario where i have to extract jar names & dependent jar names for a maven project(.pom file).These maven projects are hosted in a nexus server. Traversing through the directory structure to locate the pom file is cumbersome.

What would be the appropriate method to get those information using org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps Aether would be a good place to start? http://eclipse.org/aether/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Nexus REST API I would just call the [Maven Dependency Plugin tree goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) with a parameter for the outputFile. With that data and a bit of string parsing you can easily create a list of the filenames. From the coordinates of the output you can assemble the filenames in a repository using the [Maven repository format.](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Repository+Layout+-+Final)

Comment: Thanks Manfred. I am trying to retrieve POM files of all projects(from all repositories). All of this pom files are present in Nexus server. Is there any way i can traverse through all the POM files and pull the Jar Dependency. I know maven:dependency tree gives the dependency. But i wanted to build a custom Jar related report against a maven repository(Nexus Server)

Comment: It will potentially still be easier to use a Maven plugin. What information do you want in the report?

Comment: Jar dependency, Consumers of a jar, least used & most used jars inside a repository.

Comment: All of that information seems external to Nexus.. so I still think a Maven plugin seems easiest. Also .. the suggestion to use Aether is correct .. it is the dependency resolution library used in Maven and as such a hot candidate to be involved in the code of your Maven plugin..